# Convert silverlight to flash

Tags: silverlight, flash

How can i convert silverlight app to flash?

Comment: The same way you convert COBOL to Lolcode.  Lots of alcohol, lots of work, lots of pain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The platforms are different enough that a "conversion" of code is out of the question.

Instead take the running Silverlight app as a prototype and build the Flash from scratch.

You might be able to re-use some assets such as images.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine both platforms are turing complete.

Maybe you could embed a simple PC emulator from http://bellard.org/jslinux/ into one (or the other) of these, and install the opposing platform into it, and run it in that fashion.

Performance might suffer a bit.